# CMAKE : Build only one directory of an downloaded external project

Tags: cmake, subdirectory

### CMAKE : I only want to build part of a downloadable external project

The external project I want to use has the following structure :

```
- ExternalProject
    - Subproject A  <- this i care for
    - Subproject B
```

It's all in the same archive that is available for download. The problem is that Subproject B has more dependencies that I don't want in my project, also it's not relevant for what I'm doing. The subprojects are buildable on their own, so for now I just took *Subproject A* out of the archive and put it in my main project which is working fine, but I'd like to not deploy the external project with my project but allow the user to download the external project on his own when running cmake. Sadly there is no archive for each of the subprojects on their own so all I can download is the full external project.

What I want is to tell CMAKE to download and unpack the whole archive ExternalProject but then only add Subproject A to my project. I read all the documentation on ExternalProject_add but it mostly allows for detailed configuration of the build parameters of the project. Maybe I'm just looking for the wrong keyword and my question is really simple to answer - or it is just not possible.

If someone could point me towards the right approach here I'd be very thankful.

Actual project : 
*The mentioned archive has two subfolders "octomap" and "octovis". octomap is the one I want to build while octovis will create a lot of errors if the dependencies are not met.*

```
ExternalProject_Add(octomap-1.6.5
    URL https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap/archive/v1.6.5.tar.gz
    URL_MD5 de09b1189a03ac8cbe4f813951e86605
     SOURCE_DIR  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/octomap/
    CMAKE_ARGS "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_DIR}"
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define all commands explicitly. For instance you have a directory structure:

```
FooBar/
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - Foo/
        -      - CMakeLists.txt # You wanna build
        - Bar/
        -      - CMakeLists.txt # You wanna ignore
```

Example with hardcoded paths:

```
set(ext_dir "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/third-party-activities/ExternalProject/")
set(foobar_dir "${ext_dir}/FooBar")

ExternalProject_Add(
    FooBar
    URL "your-url-here"
    SOURCE_DIR "${foobar_dir}/Source"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND
        "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
        "-H${foobar_dir}/Source/Foo"
        "-B${foobar_dir}/Builds"
        "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_DIR}"
    BUILD_COMMAND
        "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build "${foobar_dir}/Builds"
    INSTALL_COMMAND
        "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build "${foobar_dir}/Builds" --target install
)
```

#### Update

Note that it's much easier to patch parent project like this:

```
# FooBar/CMakeLists.txt
option(BUILD_BAR_SUBPROJECT "Build targets from subproject Bar" ON)
...
add_subdirectory(Foo)
if(BUILD_BAR_SUBPROJECT)
  add_subdirectory(Bar)
endif()
```

... and now you don't need to hack ExternalProject_Add so much:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    FooBar
    URL "your-url-here"
    CMAKE_ARGS -DBUILD_BAR_SUBPROJECT=OFF "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_DIR}"
)
```

Comment: +1 - I think this works in this particular case since the project is structured so that subdirectories don't depend on any setup functionality in the top-level scope.  Generally that might not be the case, and you'd have to pass a CMake -D option in the CONFIGURE_COMMAND to disable any unwanted submodules (not always an option), or worst case - patch the project's CMakeLists.txt to disable the unwanted parts.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has put me on the right track. Regarding what CMAKE choses to build this is already perfect. My only problem now is that the EXTERNAL_INSTALL_DIR seems to be ignored now. While in my old CMAKE it made the libraries end up in my CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR/external/lib they now remain in the projects own library folder.

It seems like the  "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${EXTERNAL_INSTALL_DIR}" is ignored completely. Why would that be? Maybe the order of paramteres is wrong, so the INSTALL_COMMAND overwrites it or smth like that?

Comment: @ruslo `But I'm sure John don't want to modify external archive` - I agree. That's last case scenario stuff.  Although something as trivial and helpful as your updated answer would make a good change request to the project's maintainer... hint hint JohnTheCompilator :-)

Comment: Thanks again for all your answers. I'll look into the EXTERNAL_INSTALL_DIR again, must be on my side that I messed something else up then! 

Fraser : Yes, I will take the time to let them know about that. I don't think they've expected the project to be used that widely so they might not have even considered options like that, but it would indeem see very helpful to provide it.

ruslo : Thanks for your answer and update and for your time. Really, really helpful stuff!